# Why isn't SEL a class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, language-design

In Objective-C (at least, the Apple flavor of Obj-C), why is SEL not a class? Is it a matter of efficiency? Is it to prevent some sort of infinite recursion? Was there merely no incentive to make SEL a class? Speculation welcome, but please let me know if an answer is historical truth or speculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It goes back to the earliest versions of Objective-C. If I could find my copy of the Objective-C book, I could give you a reference, but I think it just wasn't obvious what the benefit would be. The early versions of Objective-C were very minimal extensions of the C syntax.

In GCC, the SEL type was implemented as a const char *, pointing to a string representation of the selector's name. This implementation took advantage of constant string coalescing, which was already implemented in the compiler, to ensure uniqueness of selector values.

---

"The book" of course is referring to *Object-Oriented Programming: An Evolutionary Approach*. Thanks for jogging my memory Friedrich.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: I assume this is meant:
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN%3d0201548348/virtualschoolA/
Regards
Friedrich

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thanks for the link. I think it's still well worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Making it a class type adds little or no benefit. If it were an NSObject subclass it would be a tremendous amount of overhead for something that is effectively supposed to be a unique identifier. To dispatch an Objective-C call at that point would incur a penalty such a perfomance critical section of code can't afford to pay.

And yes, I'm speculating as to justifications why the type is what it is.

Comment: It certainly couldn't be an NSObject subclass since it NSObject is not part of the core Objective-C language.

Comment: There would be no overhead related with making an SEL into a class, save for a little bit of memory.

Comment: What code section are you referring to? Most code wouldn't require dispatching messages to SELs and thus wouldn't incur any penalty. As for lack of benefits, that seems a hard statement to prove. Making data types orthogonal usually has some benefits, such as allowing all data to be stored in collections without resorting to wrapper types.